# 'map' and 'for' for the sequence comprehension

Tags: clojure

I began to learn Clojure two days ago, without any experience of functional programming. Today, when reading the reading through the book **Programming Clojure**, I met with a problem.

It's about the **transforming sequence**. There is an example:

```
(map #(format ​"<%s>%s</%s>"​ %1 %2 %1)
    [​"h1"​ ​"h2"​ ​"h3"​ ​"h1"​] [​"the"​ ​"quick"​ ​"brown"​ ​"fox"​])
```

which yields the result:

```
-> (​"<h1>the</h1>"​ ​"<h2>quick</h2>"​ ​"<h3>brown</h3>"​ "<h1>fox</h1>​"​)
```

It's not that hard for me to get it. Actually, the problem occurs when the book tells me we could use `for` to yield a sequence comprehension generally and then shows me an example. That example is kinda easy and I could totally understand it.

When I try to rewrite the example I first mentioned with `for`, the problem hit me.

I could just get:

```
("<h1>the</h1>"
"<h1>quick</h1>"
"<h1>brown</h1>"
"<h1>fox</h1>"
"<h2>the</h2>"
"<h2>quick</h2>"
"<h2>brown</h2>"
"<h2>fox</h2>"
"<h3>the</h3>"
"<h3>quick</h3>"
"<h3>brown</h3>"
"<h3>fox</h3>"
"<h1>the</h1>"
"<h1>quick</h1>"
"<h1>brown</h1>"
"<h1>fox</h1>")
```

with the rewrited code:

```
(for [label ["h1" "h2" "h3" "h1"] word ["the" "quick" "brown" "fox"]]
    (format "<%s>%s</%s>" label word label))
```

I was informed that generally using `:when` clause could somehow help, but I just could not think it out.

How could I rewrite the code with `for` so that the answer is exactly the same as the `map` version?

Comment: While for sure a good way to learn the difference between map and for, but what is gained here for forcing this into a for where the map is just the right solution?

Comment: @cfrick Aha, I'm so naive that I thought there is always a `for` version corresponding to the `map` version. Just trying to write the `for` version to check if I understand what the book wants me to know. Actually they have different use cases and may be up to one's preference!

Answer (score 5):

As you've seen when you have multiple bindings in a `for` it acts like a "nested for loop" in other imperative languages, as if you had an outer for loop for `label` and an inner for loop for `word`. So you get every combination of the two collections' values.

```
 for (label in labels)
   for (word in words)
      print(word + " " + label);
```

The simplest way I could imagine solving this problem with a `for` happens to also require `map` anyway, so I'd use your original simple `map` solution.

```
(def pairs ;; a vector of tuples/pairs of labels/words
  (map vector ["h1" "h2" "h3" "h1"] ["the" "quick" "brown" "fox"]))
;; (["h1" "the"] ["h2" "quick"] ["h3" "brown"] ["h1" "fox"])
(for [[label word] pairs] ;; enumerate each pair
  (format "<%s>%s</%s>" label word label))
=> ("<h1>the</h1>" "<h2>quick</h2>" "<h3>brown</h3>" "<h1>fox</h1>")
```

When you pass multiple collection args to `map` your mapping function receives an item from each collection for each mapping step. If you only had one input collection then the equivalent `for` would look very similar.

Comment: The only time I ever use `for` is when I need it to generate combinations of sequences, or to make use of `:while`/`:when`. `map` is definitely the right tool here.

Comment: Thanks for your clue and the explanatory analogy!

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's a perfectly fine policy for you to have, but I don't think it's "standard". Personally I'm the opposite: I only use `map` when I need multiple arguments, or when I'm passing an already-defined function. If I would need to write `(map #(...) ...)`, I prefer to use `for`. Of course in this case, `map` is indeed the right answer whatever your "personal style".

Comment: @amalloy I did try to make it clear that it's personal style. I personally stick to maps more because often when using "comprehensions", I'll need to do some pre/post processing of the produced list. When using threading, it's trivial to slip something before or after a call to `map`. Using `for` though seems to generally create more nesting, and make changing code more difficult in the future. I love `for`, but I personally treat it as a more "time and place" construct.

Comment: I mentioned it because while the other answer does likely show exactly what the assignment was looking for, it's by no means the best way. I thought that that should be emphasized.

Answer (score 2):

`for` produces a Cartesian product over all the given sequences, so one way to get corresponding pairs is to use `map-indexed`:

```
(for [[i label] (map-indexed vector ["h1" "h2" "h3" "h1"])
      [j word] (map-indexed vector ["the" "quick" "brown" "fox"])
      :when (= i j)]
  (format "<%s>%s<%s>" label word label))
```

But this requires iterating over 16 values to produce 4 values, so using `map` with 3 arguments is both more efficient and simpler.

Comment: Got it. The structure of this solution looks more like that of imperative languages, right? I'm just not that familiar with all the FP stuff. Need a lot practice! Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Ban.lo This solution is still functional. It would be like a 2D list comprehension in Python which is functional. Nothing is being mutated here which would be the main thing that would indicate that it's imperative leaning.